# Excel IQY file - Usage Option question

Tags: excel, excel-web-query

I have a simple Excel IQY file in which the contents look like this:

```
WEB
1
http://somesite.html

Selection=EntirePage
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
```

This is simple, no problems.

**What I need to do is add options that will turn ON the "Refresh data when opening the file" and turn ON "Remove data from the external data range before saving the workbook".**

I find these settings when looking at the connection properties under the "Usage" tab, but, I can't find where (or if) I can set these in the IQY file so that these two options are check on by default when using the iqy file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried an example with existing IQY file & found that those are properties of the DataRange and not the query. So, it is stored as properties of the QueryTable

Assume that you have 1 QueryTable in the Excel Sheet.
Here is the VBA code that can be used to read/set the properties, you are looking for.

Press ALT + F11  (you will see the VBA editor)
Press CTRL + G (immediate window)
Type in the following statement one by one & see what it has to say

```
Msgbox ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).RefreshOnFileOpen
Msgbox ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).SaveData
```

And then, try & set those properties from the code and see the effect of it in the DataRange properties dialog box.

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).RefreshOnFileOpen = True
ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).SaveData = True
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It then looks like the "answer" would be that I can NOT set these using the IQY file. I have not been able to find a correct setting. I do however appreciate your input and help on this. I was able to do what you suggested, but, unfortunately I am only able to pass the IQY file, not modify the spreadsheet.